# i915 cannot work with nomodeset?

Tags: linux, xorg, intel, nomodeset

I'm trying to get X to work on a ThinkPad W530. I set the BIOS to only use the integrated graphics, I attempt to boot. The display goes blank when KMS is executed and does not recover.

I append `nomodeset` or `i915.modeset=0`. Then it does boot, does not attempt to change resolution while in console mode, but I cannot start X.

I see in dmesg:

```
[drm:drm_pci_agp_init] *ERROR* Cannot initialize the agpgart module.
DRM: Fill_in_dev failed.
```

I have the latest BIOS for my system, and I've tried the kernels: 3.7.2, 3.9.5 and 3.10-rc5. This is a Slackware 14.0 64-bit distro.

It seems that the i915 module cannot work when `nomodeset` is used, and that there is some bug which makes the display turn blank. Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 1):

I am using i915 module on RHEL 6.4 . I had some problem with X in the begining. Instead of color, I was getting greyscale display. After setting NOMODESET kernel parameter in /etc/grub.conf file, everything worked fine and I am getting a color display.

SO i915 works with NOMODESET.

Thanks,
Stany